# Disabling an image just as you can do with a button

Tags: html, image, button, javascript

```
 document.getElementById("buttonName").disabled=true;
```

So I know you can disable a button using this code. But i use pictures as buttons and they have an onClick function which i want to be able to disable. Is there any way to do this?

Also, only javascript, not jquery (if possible).

Comment: Remove the event handler, and add it back to re-enable.

Comment: Why don't you just use `<input type="image" />` to continue using the `disabled` ability?

Comment: use document.getElementById("buttonName").onclick = null;

Comment: If you have some event handler already attached to it. Then try this document.getElementById("buttonName").removeEventListener('click', callbackMethodIfAny);

Comment: @Ian because I want the picture to be disabled onClick, when the site loads up for the first time I want it to work.

Comment: @user3561779 I know, I get your point. So you use this HTML: `<input id="buttonName" type="image" src="path to image" />`, and then when you want it disabled, use your code: `document.getElementById("buttonName").disabled=true;`

Answer (score -1, accepted):

You can set onclick to null for your image-button to disable its onclick event.

```
document.getElementById("buttonName").onclick = null;
```

if you need to set a function to onclick event again:

```
document.getElementById("buttonName").onclick = funcToRun;
```

Comment: Thank you that works perfectly, do you know how to enable it again after it has been disabled? (I will mark as answer as soon as i can)

Comment: you can enable it but setting the function to run to onclick attribute. added above

Comment: I don't know why you got down-voted, maybe it was a bad question by me? Sorry. But you sure helped me out, so thanks!